# Thinking I need an "=IF" statement

Tags: excel-formula

I have a sheet with over 6000 lines.  The sheet has 2 lines per recruit.  I need a formula that will search column M for a "Y", and when found, will return the value of a cell that is 5 columns to the left and one row up from said "Y".  Is there such a formula?

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezzbL.jpg)

My Desired result is (on a new sheet) everywhere there is a "Y" for Appointment Made, I'll return the values in the line below the "Y".

I hope this clarifies my question.

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: please mock up some data and expected output.  Insert that as a plain text table in the original post using [edit].

Comment: you can try the offset() function with match(), but with that amount of data it will probably choke on the recalculations required when you change something...

Answer (score 0):

Offset the return '5 columns to the left and one row up'.

```
=index(h$1:h$6999, match("Y", m$2:m$7000, 0))
```

That gets the first one but only the first one. To get the first, second, third, etc. use aggregate instead of match with row(1:1) supplying the *k* parameter and fill down.

```
=index(h:h, aggregate(15, 6, row($1:h$6999)/(m$2:m$7000="Y"), row(1:1)))
```